# Set a max value for a custom field in salesforce of type number

Tags: custom-object, custom-field, number

I have created a custom field in a custom object of type Number(2,1) in salesforce. Please let me know how set a max value for this field.

Comment: You can use validation rules - refer here for details https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_useful_validation_formulas_number.htm&language=en_US

Comment: hi @r-s-k done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use validation rules to restrict the values (max / min) in the custom number field - refer [this salesforce help article](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_useful_validation_formulas_number.htm&language=en_US) for details with samples

Answer (score 1):

S.K,
             Whenever you create new field in salesforce for example you want to create new number field then choose number then do next in next page under field label you see "Length" and "decimal". And this lines. "Please enter the length of the number and the number of decimal places. For example, a number with a length of 8 and 2 decimal places can accept values up to "12345678.90".
So from here you can define max length of this field. And if you want to define maximum value then write a validation rule for this.
Thanks,
Pritam Shekhawat

Answer (score 1):

You can use validation rule to restrict the max. value of number field.